# Menu Item in action bar not working

Tags: android

Hi I added the menu file ,there are 3 Menu Items:

1) Menu Pin,

2) Send Reply and

3) Add Notes.

Send Reply , Add Notes are working fine but, when removed comment for pin, it is not working. I attached the code below.

Please suggest me any solution. When I paste the code of Send Reply to pin_menu case for testing purpose it is not working.

Log cat doesn't show anything.I added the toast on click of pin_menu it doesn't show.Please suggest me solution.

I also tried to add one extra menu in XML file and added  the code same as the pin_menu but not worked. Doesn't show log cat ,toast. So that hard to debug.Same for Send Reply and Add Note but both are working fine.

Code is as below:

```
 <item android:id="@+id/menu_pin"
      android:icon="@drawable/pin"
      android:title="@string/pin"
      android:showAsAction="never" 
      />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_send_reply"
      android:icon="@drawable/send"
      android:title="@string/send_reply"
      android:showAsAction="never" 
      />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_add_note"
      android:icon="@drawable/add_note"
      android:title="@string/add_note"
      android:showAsAction="never" 
       />
```

```
                            @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
                    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.ticket_properties_menu, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                    Log.d("DATA ","Item ID "+item.getItemId());
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (item.getItemId())
                    {
                    case R.id.menu_add_note:

                        Intent i3 = new Intent(Ticket_properties.this,Add_note.class);
                        i3.putExtra("ID", Ticket_id);
                        i3.putExtra("client_id", client_id);
                        startActivity(i3);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.menu_send_reply:

                        Intent reply= new Intent(Ticket_properties.this,Send_reply.class);
                        reply.putExtra("ticket_id", Ticket_id);
                        reply.putExtra("title", Ticket_title);
                        reply.putExtra("dept_id", tv_dept_id.getText());
                        reply.putExtra("Ticket_hash", Ticket_hash);
                        reply.putExtra("filter_id",filter_id);
                        startActivity(reply);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.menu_pin:

                        Intent reply1= new Intent(Ticket_properties.this,Send_reply.class);
                        reply1.putExtra("ticket_id", Ticket_id);
                        reply1.putExtra("title", Ticket_title);
                        reply1.putExtra("dept_id", tv_dept_id.getText());
                        reply1.putExtra("Ticket_hash", Ticket_hash);
                        reply1.putExtra("filter_id",filter_id);
                        startActivity(reply1);
                        return true;

                        /*
                      String PIN_URL=op.getUrl(Ticket_properties.this,"ticket", "add_pinup","&vis_ticket_id=124");
                      JSONArray pin_result = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(PIN_URL+"&vis_encode=json",Ticket_properties.this);
                      String result =pin_result.toString();
                      if(result.equals("[\"success\"]"))
                      {             
                            Operation.showToast(getApplicationContext(),R.string.pinned);           
                      }
                      */

                  default:
                        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                    }


                }
```

Comment: What do u mean by removed comment for pin? You have removed the title of the menu in menu.xml?

Comment: Can u post the logcat?

Comment: case R.id.menu_add_note was commented ,I remove the comments now in the code.I want to add this menu in the app.

Comment: There is nothing in the logcat.

Comment: 11-07 05:25:07.832: I/Choreographer(4168): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    11-07 05:25:08.002: I/Choreographer(4168): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    11-07 05:25:11.212: I/Choreographer(4168): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: You mean when you hit the pin menu item - you are trying to navigate to Send_reply activity and its not navigating to that activity?

Comment: I want to execute the commented code int he case R.id,Menu_pin:

Comment: What response you r getting for the call JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(PIN_URL+"&vis_encode=json",Ticket_properties.this)?

Comment: I just want to hit om pin menu and execute the  PIN_URL.

Comment: Is Navigation working or not ?
Like as you are moving data to Send_reply, is it working for you ?

Comment: @DeepakSachdeva I got confused with that, but in the conversation with him so far... he don't want to navigate, he just needs to get the json as I understand. Looks like he is getting Network on main thread exception.

Comment: Now currently I cant debug anything due to Log cat doesn't show anything .But  response will be "success" .

Comment: @SandeepT please check in the logs when you click on menu_pin you are getting NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: @Deepak : Yes navigation working for Send_reply and Add_notes. There is  no any navigation in the Pin_menu ,it just add the particular data to the database using API.

Comment: @SandeepT Firstly use simple Toast to check that the code is going to executed or not in menu_pin.

Comment: @SandeepT do what Deepak said. And put the code which you are trying to execute in asyntask and try.

Comment: @SandeepT Right, If you want to execute your code then as Raghavendra said implement AsycTask.

Comment: Currently tried try catch for exception but there is not any exception , second is Toast doesn't show. I am new to android. doesn't know much more about the android like asyntask .

Comment: Try this for AsycTask
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you are using this commented code on the wrong place. You should use it before return, in the switch case structure. If you want to trigger it on pin clicked. Here is the updated code;

```
@Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.ticket_properties_menu, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                Log.d("DATA ","Item ID "+item.getItemId());
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                case R.id.menu_add_note:

                    Intent i3 = new Intent(Ticket_properties.this,Add_note.class);
                    i3.putExtra("ID", Ticket_id);
                    i3.putExtra("client_id", client_id);
                    startActivity(i3);
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_send_reply:

                    Intent reply= new Intent(Ticket_properties.this,Send_reply.class);
                    reply.putExtra("ticket_id", Ticket_id);
                    reply.putExtra("title", Ticket_title);
                    reply.putExtra("dept_id", tv_dept_id.getText());
                    reply.putExtra("Ticket_hash", Ticket_hash);
                    reply.putExtra("filter_id",filter_id);
                    startActivity(reply);
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_pin:

                                          String PIN_URL=op.getUrl(Ticket_properties.this,"ticket", "add_pinup","&vis_ticket_id=124");
                  JSONArray pin_result = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(PIN_URL+"&vis_encode=json",Ticket_properties.this);
                  String result =pin_result.toString();
                  if(result.equals("[\"success\"]"))
                  {             
                        Operation.showToast(getApplicationContext(),R.string.pinned);           
                  }
                    Intent reply1= new Intent(Ticket_properties.this,Send_reply.class);
                    reply1.putExtra("ticket_id", Ticket_id);
                    reply1.putExtra("title", Ticket_title);
                    reply1.putExtra("dept_id", tv_dept_id.getText());
                    reply1.putExtra("Ticket_hash", Ticket_hash);
                    reply1.putExtra("filter_id",filter_id);
                    startActivity(reply1);
                    return true;

              default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }


            }
```